# Why sqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQuery() is blocked?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, deadlock

I have an C# application that connect to SQL Server 2008R2 with the connection string `Asynchronous Processing=true;` and `MultipleActiveResultSets=True;`

The application has multiple threads and each open its own connection to access the database.

Most of the time the application works, but occasionally some of these thread were blocked at the following code:

```
IAsyncResult asyncResult = sqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
int rowsAffected = sqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQuery(asyncResult);
```

`sqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQuery()` never returns, or times out.

I check the stacktrace:

```
Child SP         IP               Call Site
000000000242d608 00000000778618ca [HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ: 000000000242d608] System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, UInt32, Boolean, Boolean)
000000000242d740 000007fef795bf64 System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle, Int64, Boolean, Boolean)
000000000242d780 000007fee438bed6 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.WaitForAsyncResults(System.IAsyncResult)
000000000242d7c0 000007fee438baf1 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQuery(System.IAsyncResult)
```

I have set the `sqlCommand.CommandTimeout` to 30 sec, but I can't figure out why this problem happen occasionally.

I checked if SQL Server has blocked sessions, but there isn't. Is it possible because there are multiple connections own by the same application, and somehow they blocked each other?

Comment: You do understand that by calling BeginXyz and then *immediately* calling EndXyz, you're basically doing the same as a synchronous Xyz call?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, that's correct. I will have to look at the history of the code and see why it was like that. Otherwise I will change it to sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Answer (score 1):

It does appear this code is pointless, but you should check the IsCompleted flag on the asyncResult object. Calling EndExecuteNonQuery if IsCompleted is false will end up blocking.

Comment: I think you are right. I just check API and I should check the IsCompleted. I need to test this out because this issue doesn't happen enough for me to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I checked the documentation, calling EndExecuteNonQuery will be block until the operation is finished: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b6f9k7k.aspx.  In one of the MS examples, it doesn't check the IsComplete. So I don't think that's the cause of the issue. As @Jon point out this code is synchronous anyways, so I will change it and see if it resolve the problem.